# Loading large blocks of text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am working on a project that allows users to view log files of their projects that are stored on the server.

To reduce the amount of requests made to a server, once a log file is requested I store it in an array, and then load directly from there if it is requested again.

The way I am loading it is by using $('#log').html(text), and this causes a bit of a delay when I load the text into the div (It is about 65k of text).

Is there a better way to do this, or is this always going to cause some sort of delay?

Comment: The delay could be due to your log markup. Show us a snip.

Comment: You could have the text of all logs in the DOM and then use `.hide()` and `.show()` to display the individual logs... That should definitively be faster than appending a large amount of text into the DOM.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas That might be faster, but it would increase the load on the server needlessly by having the page load logs that might never be viewed. OP is trying to reduce the number of server requests.

Comment: @mblase75 My suggestion was not do load all logs beforehand. The logs would still be retrieved by explicit request. However, instead of removing and appending them to the DOM (which is what the OP currently does), I would have them in the DOM at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the log text is just text and not HTML markup, use `.text()` instead of `.html()`:

```
$( '#log' ).text( text );
```

That should speed things up.